# flask url parameters gives error

Tags: python, html, flask

I am getting the following error:

> "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint
>   'setpassword'. Did you forget to specify values ['token']?"

main.py:

```
@app.route('/setpassword/<token>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def setpassword(token):
    form = PasswordForm()
    return render_template('setpassword.html',form=form, token=token)
```

setpassword.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% from '_macros.html' import hello %}

{% block title %}SetPassword{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for i in form.password.validators %}
{{ i.message }}
{% endfor %}
<form class="form form-horizontal " action="{{ url_for('setpassword') }}"     method=post role="form">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.password, hiddens='True',placeholder='Enter Password') }}
    {% for e in form.password.errors %}
        <span class="label label-danger" id="labelerror">{{ e }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.confirm, class='form-control' , placeholder='Confirm Password') }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit , class='btn btn-primary btn-block' ) }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Why is this error occurring and how do I stop it occurring?

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` takes keyword arguments for the variables. So you can write the action url like this

```
<form action="{{ url_for('setpassword', token=token) }}">
```

Comment: Looked promising, but still getting the same error.

Comment: When you render_template did you pass `token` to `setpassword.html`

Comment: return render_template('setpassword.html',form=form, token=token)

Comment: Can you attach your full traceback

Comment: If I just use "return token" I will get the value. I dont even need to render the token. I just want to be able to return a template and still be able to use a parameter in the url.

Comment: If you trying to render the template that contains the url_for and that expect keyword variable and you not passing that in the context then do whatever value you have . i.e) `<form action="{{ url_for('setpassword', token='something') }}">`

Comment: The problem I had was that in my base.html I had a button that implemented
"<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('setpassword',token=token) }}" role="button">Set password</a>"
Thanks for the help

Comment: Using that technique in base.html is bad but we will get through this. Can you exactly tell me this error little bit.  what url you trying to access and when this error occur ? I asked you to post the full traceback but you haven't. '